# Cannot convert value of type '[NSManagedObject]' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a function I've found on this site related to deleting from core data with swipe function from tableview, but I can't figure out what this error message is requiring me to do? Can someone help with this error please?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectRandom: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var removeName: UIButton!



    var people: [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Spiller"
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self


        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Player")
        do {
            people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }


    @IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nytt navn",
                                      message: "Legg til ny spiller",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Lagre", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

            guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
                let nameToSave = textField.text else {
                    return
            }

            self.save(name: nameToSave)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Avbryt",
                                         style: .default)

        alert.addTextField()

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    func save(name: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Player",
                                                in: managedContext)!

        let Player = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                     insertInto: managedContext)

        Player.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            people.append(Player)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Kunne ikke lagre. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
    @IBAction func randomPlayer(_ sender: UIButton) {


    }
    @IBAction func extraGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    @IBAction func walkOver(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    @IBAction func trash(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if removeName.isEnabled{


        }

        }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


            }
        }


// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Player = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                                 for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Player.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        return cell
    }
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let noteEntity = "Player" //Entity Name

            let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

            let note = people[indexPath.row]

            if editingStyle == .delete {
                managedContext.delete(people)

                do {
                    try managedContext.save()
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Error While Deleting Note: \(error.userInfo)")
                }

            }

            //Code to Fetch New Data From The DB and Reload Table.
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: noteEntity)

            do {
                people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Player]
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error While Fetching Data From DB: \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
if editingStyle == .delete {
  managedContext.delete(people)
```

as `managedContext.delete` takes an argument of type `NSManagedObject` and currently you're passing `people` which is `[NSManagedObject]`

you have to delete note

```
managedContext.delete(note)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you assign or pass somewhere an array where a single item is expected.

You want to delete one note (`NSManagedObject`)

```
let note = people[indexPath.row]
```

but you are going to delete the entire array (`[NSManagedObject]`)

```
managedContext.delete(people)
```

There is the error, it's just a typo, you have to write

```
managedContext.delete(note)
```